# Change color of magnifying glass

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

The color of a magnifying glass is being taken automatically from the background color of UITextView.
Under the text view I have an image and the text view background itself is opaque. So in this case the magnifying glass is white even though the picture under UITextView is yellow.

Is it possible to override the color of magnifying glass?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the time of writing, it was not possible on a non jailbroken iPhone.

Now, see the answer from @Parthpatel1105

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for change colour of search magnify .

```
- (UIImage *)tintedImageWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor image:(UIImage *)image {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

// draw alpha-mask
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image.CGImage);

// draw tint color, preserving alpha values of original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
[tintColor setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return coloredImage;
```

}

use this line when you pass image object to search bar.

```
    UIImage *obj_image = [self tintedImageWithColor:[appDelegate.appDefaultdata valueForKey:@"d_colorA"] image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_magnify.png"]];
[contactSearchbar setImage:obj_image forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UITextView/UITextField`, override `-drawRect` and do your own drawing, then you can use `.backgroundColor` to set the magnifying glass tint.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11979511/2819388) thread provides different solutions. I prefered the one labeled with "dirty hack", instead of the one marked as "solution".

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 5, you can use the following API:

```
UISearchBar.setImage(:forSearchBarIcon:state:)
```

It's easiest to just provide your own icon. If you like to tint it dynamically, you can provide your own icon and Core Graphics to create a new tinted version before setting it on the search bar.