# Change UISearchbar Magnifying Glass Color, PlaceHolder Color, and X Color

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uicolor

I've searched various solutions to accomplish this task but they are either in objective C or involve replacing the magnifying glass image.

[image]

[image]

Previous Posts I looked at:

[Change color of magnifying glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977019/change-color-of-magnifying-glass)

[How to change UISearchBar Placeholder and image tint color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375696/how-to-change-uisearchbar-placeholder-and-image-tint-color)

The reason I dont want to replace the image of the magnifying glass is because the page color is dynamic and there are over 100+ color combinations

Any help on changing the UISearchbar Magnifying Glass Color, PlaceHolder Color, and X Color would greatly be appreciated

Comment: have you tried those posts you looked at ? Forget about replacing the image. What about placeholder colour and tint colour? Did you try anything?

Comment: Have you look at this tutorial yet: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/

Comment: @Mr.T I've replaced the tintcolor which changes the font color of the typed text and cancel button but not the placeholder or X button.

Comment: One of the posts you looked at suggests a way to change the placeholder colour , did u try that ?

Comment: @Mr.T I got the place holder textcolor to change using attributedtext properties. I'm still working on figuring out how to change the X and magnifying glass

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944781/how-to-change-the-tint-color-of-the-clear-button-on-a-uitextfield

Comment: @Mr.T would this be considered as modifying a private property or api which would result in my app getting rejected from the app store?

Answer (score 15):

Objective C :

```
NSArray *searchBarSubViews = [[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
for (UIView *view in searchBarSubViews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)view;
        UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)textField.leftView;
        imgView.image = [imgView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        imgView.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIButton *btnClear = (UIButton*)[textField valueForKey:@"clearButton"];
        [btnClear setImage:[btnClear.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnClear.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }
}
[self.searchBar reloadInputViews];
```

Swift :

```
// Text field in search bar.
let textField = searchController.searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as! UITextField

let glassIconView = textField.leftView as! UIImageView
glassIconView.image = glassIconView.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
glassIconView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let clearButton = textField.valueForKey("clearButton") as! UIButton
clearButton.setImage(clearButton.imageView?.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate), forState: .Normal)
clearButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Shahil's answer updated for Swift 3:**

```
let textField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField

let glassIconView = textField.leftView as! UIImageView
glassIconView.image = glassIconView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
glassIconView.tintColor = .white


let clearButton = textField.value(forKey: "clearButton") as! UIButton
clearButton.setImage(clearButton.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
clearButton.tintColor = .white
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func setupPlaceHolder(text: String, textColor: UIColor) {
  searchBar.searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
    string: text,
    attributes: [.foregroundColor: textColor]
  )
        
  searchBar.searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .white
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer. Also, code-only answers are not considered very helpful. it's best to explain what the code does and how it solves the issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

##### For 2024

```
class UsableUISearchBar: UISearchBar {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        common()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        common()
    }

    func common() {
        barTintColor = .clear
        searchTextField.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        searchTextField.leftView?.tintColor = .white
    }
}
```

Yes, init seems to be late enough to set the colors. (Obviously, depending on your house style you could do it in layout.)